# Service override doesn't work as expected

Tags: php, symfony, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I create a service inside my module with the name of an existing core service (`prestashop.adapter.data_provider.product`). It successfully replaces it as seen in `php ./bin/console debug:container` output.

In yaml:

```
prestashop.adapter.data_provider.product:   
   class: PrestaShop\Module\MyModule\Adapter\Product\ProductDataProvider
```

The problem now is that I have 500 errors in some pages in BO. These errors are type errors like:

> Type error: Argument 4 passed to
> PrestaShopBundle\Model\Product\AdminModelAdapter::__construct() must
> be an instance of
> PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Adapter\Product\ProductDataProvider, instance of
> PrestaShop\Module\MyModule\Adapter\Product\ProductDataProvider given,
> called in....

I understand now that, whenever a constructor has an argument of type `ProductDataProvider`, the app tries to load my service but find a different`use` statement in the class (i.e in `PrestaShopBundle\Model\Product\AdminModelAdapter`)

These errors can be fixed by replacing the `use` statement in each file containing the problem, but as you may know, touching core files must be avoided.

Is there a way of overriding an existing service, but also make the override work all across the app "bypassing the `use` statements of the old service".

Comment: Does your custom ProductDataProvider extend the default ProductDataProvider?  I am guessing not.

Comment: @Cerad = a hero like years ago. Thanks a lot. I forgot to extend.